# Italic font doesnt work when adding custom font to parsed HTML content in UITextView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, ios10, nsattributedstring

I have a textview where I'm parsing and HTML content and it works fine. But the tags marked italic doesn't work. I'm using a custom font. Below is the sample code:

```
NSString *messages = @"<b>Bold</b><br><i>Italic</i><p> <del>Deleted</del><p>List<ul><li>Coffee</li><li type='square'>Tea</li></ul><br><a href='URL'>Link </a>";

NSString *stringWithFont = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: OpenSans; font-size: 14\">%@</span>", messages];

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                                initWithData: [stringWithFont dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                                documentAttributes: nil
                                                error: nil
                                                ];

_notificationTextView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

This is how it looks, note that the italic didn't work.

[image]

## UPDATE

Currently my project includes all Opensans font set like, regular, italic, bold, semibold etc. So, if I remove the light font or its reference from my project it seems to work. Looks like some kind of weird conflict with regular and light font. Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: your bundle contain that Italic font?

Comment: Yes its added to the bundle, this are the font file that I use http://www.mediafire.com/file/cpjerw9wwipppmq/OpenSansFont.zip

Comment: and it is also added in plist right ?

Comment: Yes, its also added in plist. If you are interested you can check out the demo project for this issue here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/d1q5ipxwjqfd62r/CustomFontTest.zip

Comment: @ravi.p It's not like the italic font doesn't work at all, since its an HTML string currently I'm appending it to use OpenSans. So it should automatically detects bold italic etc.If I specify to use OpenSans-Italic, that works, but all texts are italics.

Comment: try to add <p> put your html text </p>

Comment: Tried that but didnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126108/discussion-between-ravi-p-and-gamerlegend).

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Showing italic text. Use

```
     self.txtView.attributedText=attributedString;
```